# RestClient работает, а HttpClient не работает | C#

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient

Есть запрос на получение картинки. Я проверил его в Postman и скопировал сгенерированный код в C#:

```
var client = new RestClient();
var request = new RestRequest("https://shadowcraft.ru/engine/modules/antibot/antibot.php", Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("referer", "https://shadowcraft.ru/");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request2); // 200 OK
```

Он работает прекрасно, но я хочу использовать HttpClient.

Я пытался сделать так, однако получаю ошибку 520:

```
var client2 = new HttpClient();
var request2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://shadowcraft.ru/engine/modules/antibot/antibot.php");
request2.Headers.Add("referer", "https://shadowcraft.ru/");
var response2 = await client.SendAsync(request2); // 520 error
```

**Код почти 1 в 1, что не так?**

P.S. у меня такое уже не первый раз, что RestClient работает, а строчка в строчку написанный HttpClient - нет.

Comment: "Код почти 1 в 1", ну ну, и ссылки прям тоже "одинаковые"...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это опечатка, суть не меняет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, разобрался. Дело в User-Agent. Насколько я понимаю в RestClient он передаёться по умолчанию.

Просто добавил

```
request2.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36");
```

Comment: Вынесите создание клиента в статичное поле, его надо создавать 1 раз, а не на каждый запрос `private static readonly HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient();` и воткните агента в заголовки по умолчанию в мэйне или конструкторе, чтобы выполнилось 1 раз `client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36");` и последнее, запрос и ответ надо диспозить `using var request2 = ...;`, `using var response2 = ...;`, вот тогда будет красиво и быстро работать.

Comment: @aepot да, я так всегда и делаю, но для вопроса на стековерфлоу лучше писать как я написал, что-бы было легко скопировать и воспроизвести код

Comment: `using` прописать лаконичности не помешает, но может оказаться критичным в некоторых ситуациях. Так, на будущее. :)

Comment: @aepot тоже вкурсе, но всёравно спасибо)